# css file in static folder is not applied to the web page

Tags: django

I have given STATIC_URL, STATIC_ROOT, STATICFILES_DIRS in **settings.py** and used them in **home.html**

I have given all the requirements to have static files. All the files in static folder are loaded and accessible on webpage but the css file is not applied to the webpage.

I once again gone through the documentation to setup static files but the style is applied and there is no error while run on localhost

SETTINGS.PY:

```
      STATIC_URL = '/static/'
      STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assest')
      STATICFILES_DIRS = [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
            'C:/Users/RK/Documents/py/Django/jangosite/portfolio/static/',
            ]
```

HOME.HTML:

```
   {% extends 'portfolio/base.html' %}
   {% load static %}
   {% block extrahead %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 
      '/portfolio/style.css' %}">
   {% endblock %}
   {% block content %}   
   <h1>hello!!!</h1>
   <p>Hai, i am RATHINA KARTHI T studying in SRM VEC.I am a Computer 
    Science Engineer</p>
   <a id="myresume" href="{% static '/portfolio/resume.pdf' %}">resume</a>
   <br>
   <a id="myblogs" href="{% url 'blog:ablog' %}">go to blogs</a>
   <br>
   <img src="{% static 'portfolio/k.jpg' %}" height="40" width="50">
   <br>
   {% for p in projects %}
   <h2>{{ p.title }}</h2>
   <p>{{ p.description }}</p>
   <img src="{{ p.image.url }}" height="40" width="50">
   {% if p.link %}
   <a href="{{ p.link }}">link</a>
   {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
   {% endblock %}
```

Here all the static files are avasilable in webpage(eg. k.jpg and resume.pdf) but the style.css file is not applied to web page which is also present in the same path. i have tried to save it in a inner folder named css and gave that path in html and that is also not worked

Comment: So can you show us what you have tried?... We can't help if we don't see anything

Comment: @Gryu hope this is enough , if it is not pls correct me ,thank you

Comment: @Lemayzeur sure , i am new to this stack overflow i have added the image link coz i need reputations to add image directly.pls refer the link and added the code as text as Gryu said ,hope this is enough to understand my problem ,otherwise help me to improve my ability to ask question properly , thank you

Answer (score 0):

try adding this ur settings

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
 )
```

Comment: i have added this code to my settings.py,but even now the css style  is not applied sir